# Diffeomorphism Preserves Tangency (Do Carmo 2.4.25)

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

Suppose $C_1$ and $C_2$ are regular curves on a regular surface $S$. Suppose $p$ is a point in $S$ where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are tangent, then if $\varphi:S\rightarrow S$ is a diffeomorphism, prove that $\varphi(C_1)$ and $\varphi(C_2)$ are regular curves which are tangent at $\varphi(p)$.

How would I start this? What would I need to show?

Comment: As a start, can you write out in formulas what it means for $C_1$ and $C_2$ to be tangent at $p$?

Comment: @quarague Do you mean they have the same tangent plane at $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, we have to show that if $\varphi:S_{1}\rightarrow S_{2}$ is a diffeomorphism, and $C$ is a regular curve on $S_{1}$, then $\varphi(C)$ is a regular curve on $S_{2}$. To do so, let $\alpha:I\rightarrow S_{1}$ be a parametrization of $C_{1}$. Then $\varphi\circ\alpha:I\rightarrow S_{2}$ is a parametrization of $C_{2}$, and we have 
   $$\tag{1}\label{1}
   (\varphi\circ\alpha)'(t)=d_{\alpha(t)}\varphi(\alpha'(t)).
   $$
   You should check that this expression is nonzero. Can you see why this is the case?
2. Next, we have two curves $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ that are tangent at $p$. This means that their velocity vectors at $p$ are parallel, i.e. there are parametrizations $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$ of $C_{1}$ resp. $C_{2}$ such that $\alpha_{1}(0)=\alpha_{2}(0)=p$ and
   $$\tag{2}\label{2}
   \alpha_{1}'(0)=c\alpha_{2}'(0).
   $$
   To show that $\varphi(C_{1})$ and $\varphi(C_{2})$ are tangent at $\varphi(p)$, we have to show that their velocity vectors $(\varphi\circ\alpha_{1})'(0)$ and $(\varphi\circ\alpha_{2})'(0)$ are parallel. Can you see that this follows from \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}?

Comment: Yes that pretty much answers my question thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, the fact that $\varphi\circ \alpha$ is a parametrization allows one to assert that the differential is nonzero correct?

Comment: @JB071098 The expression (1) above is nonzero because $\alpha'(t)$ is nonzero (since $\alpha$ is regular) and $d_{\alpha(t)}\varphi$ is an isomorphism (since $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism).